# Неправильно читается файл

Tags: c#

Всем привет, скажите, у меня неправильно читается файл, есть 5-я строка, которая содержит в себе число 25. Так вот я записал это число из comboBox'a при помощи класса BinaryWriter... А когда хочу прочитать этот файл обратно при помощи класса BinaryReader, использую такую вещь:

```
int month = 0;
int years = 0;

FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"Data" + DateTime.Now.Month + "." + DateTime.Now.Day + ".data", FileMode.Open);

BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

string month1 = br.ReadString();
day = br.ReadInt32();
br.ReadInt32();
br.ReadInt32();
int num = br.ReadInt32();   // Вот где должно читаться число 25
br.Close();
```

Но почему-то мне выводит не 25, а какое-то большое и страшное число. Где я допустил ошибку?

Код записи в файл:

```
string Male = string.Empty;
int data = 0;

data = Convert.ToInt32(comboDay.SelectedItem);

if (radioMen.Checked == true)
    Male = "Мужчина";
if (radioWomen.Checked == true)
    Male = "Женщина";

DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("Data");
dir.Create();

FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"Data" + comboMonth.SelectedItem.ToString() + "." + comboDay.SelectedItem.ToString() + ".data", FileMode.Create);
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);

bw.Write(textName.Text);
bw.Write(Male);
bw.Write(comboYear.SelectedItem.ToString());
bw.Write(comboMonth.SelectedItem.ToString());
bw.Write(data.ToString());
bw.Write(checkAll.SelectedItem.ToString());
bw.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Успешно сохранено");
```

Comment: Покажите код, записывающий число в файл.

Comment: А вот как пишется/читается ваша строка? Как `BinaryReader` узнает где заканчивается строка, а где начинаются данные?

Comment: Добавил в первый пост.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что записываете вы строку, строку, строку и ещё несколько строк, а считываете строку, число, число, число и число.

Извольте сделать чтение соответствующее записи.

Comment: Я сомневаюсь, что даже чтение всех строк поможет.

Comment: В чём проблема? Записали пять строк -- считали пять строк.

Comment: сделал сохранение в int, так весь файл стал убогим

errgРњСѓР¶С‡РёРЅР°19033

Comment: Не пугайтесь, просто int'ы записываются байт-кодом. Если вы всё сделали правильно, считывание должно работать.

Comment: УРА! СПАСИБО ВСЁ РАБОТАЕТ!!